# List<Uri>.OrderBy() sort order based upon Contains()?

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have a standard `List<Uri>` defined that contains a short list of items.  I'd like to iterate over the list using a foreach() but would like to 'bring to the top' those items that contain a specific string value in order to process them first.  Is this possible with the OrderBy() and, better yet, is it possible in a single line?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that:

```
foreach(var uri in uriList.OrderByDescending(uri => uri.ToString().Contains("foo"))
{
    // Use uri
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes. you can use `OrderByDescending()` using an order that returns a boolean - example:

```
var results = items.OrderByDescending( x => x.Name=="Herbert").ToList();
```

In this case the order would return `true` for "Herbert" and `false` for all other values. All `true` values will be ordered *after* all `false` values - we reverse the order by using `OrderByDescending()` and have the desired outcome.

Adapted to your `Uri` list and `Contains()` which also returns a boolean this would mean:

```
foreach(var uri in uriList.OrderByDescending(x => x.ToString().Contains(someString))
{
   //..
}
```

Comment: Just FYI - AbsoluteUri will throw with certain types of Uri instances.  Not sure what's stored in this list, but if you're storing relative Uri information, use `ToString()` or a different property...

Comment: *All true values will be ordered after all false values* -> is there any guarantee for that? Where is it written? Can you help?

Answer (score 4):

The others used OrderByDescending, which will work, but you asked for using OrderBy, so here:

```
yourList.OrderBy(u => u.AbsoluteUri.Contains("somevalue") ? string.Empty : u.AbsoluteUri);
```

Comment: Thanks for attempting to stay within the confines of my question, but it was phrased in ignorance but I'm glad to see it can be done in another way.